# How do you set the duration time of a launch screen in xcode?

Tags: swift

I have a launch screen in my ios app and I'm trying to set the duration time for it, so it will show up on the screen for longer. How do I do this?

Comment: I think this has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111611/2894790

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: how to delay the launch screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028449/ios-how-to-delay-the-launch-screen)

Answer (score 1):

Add this into appdelegate.m inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

[RNSplashScreen show];

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.000];//time delay

return YES;